# Simple_Html_Dom parser not working inside function

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use Simple_Html_Dom parser to parse a web page for NBA statistics. I'm going to have a lot of different urls, but parsing the same data, so I figured I would create a function. Outside of the function, this parser works great, however as soon as I place the parsing inside the function, I receive a connection error. Just wondering, if anyone knows why I can't run the file_get_html inside the function. Here is the code below. Please help!

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$nbaPlayers = 'playerstats/15/1/eff/1-2';

function nbaStats($url){
    $html = 'http://www.hoopsstats.com/basketball/fantasy/nba/';
    $getHtml = $html . $url;
    $a = file_get_html("$getHtml");

    foreach($a->find('.statscontent tbody tr') as $tr){
        $nbaStatLine = $tr->find('td');
        $nbaName = $nbaStatLine[1]->plaintext;
        $nbaGamesPlayed = $nbaStatLine[2]->plaintext;
        $nbaMinuesPlayed = $nbaStatLine[3]->plaintext;
        $nbaTotalPoints = $nbaStatLine[4]->plaintext;
        $nbaRebounds = $nbaStatLine[5]->plaintext;
        $nbaAssists = $nbaStatLine[6]->plaintext;
        $nbaSteals = $nbaStatLine[7]->plaintext;
        $nbaBlocks = $nbaStatLine[8]->plaintext;
        $nbaTurnovers = $nbaStatLine[9]->plaintext;
        $nbaoRebounds = $nbaStatLine[11];
        $nbadRebounds = $nbaStatLine[12];
        $nbaFieldGoals = $nbaStatLine[13];
        $nbaFieldGoals = explode("-", $nbaFieldGoals);
        $nbaFieldGoalsMade = $nbaFieldGoals[0];
        $nbaFieldGoalsAttempted = $nbaFieldGoals[1];
        // Player Stat Line
        $playerStats = $nbaName . ': gp - ' . $nbaGamesPlayed . ' mp - ' . $nbaMinutesPlayed . ' pts - ' . $nbaTotalPoints . ' rb - ' . $nbaRebounds . ' as - ' . $nbaAssists . ' s - ' . $nbaSteals . ' bl - ' . $nbaBlocks . ' to - ' . $nbaTurnovers;

        echo $playerStats . '<br /><br />';
    }
}
nbaStats($nbaPlayers);
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing a variable to a function you don't need to wrap the variable in quotations. Quotations are used when passing text directly to a function or assigning text to a variable.

Change this:

```
$a = file_get_html("$getHtml");
```

To this:

```
$a = file_get_html($getHtml);
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, but I've already tried both ways to no avail. Just tried again after your post and still no good. My local wamp server app crashes and still get connection error.

Comment: There may be something wrong in addition to what I posted but the fact that you're trying to pass a variable as a string is definitely part of the issue. In PHP there is something called a type system (as there is in many languages). The fact that you wrapped the variable name in quotations leads PHP to believe that "$getHTML" is the url you're trying to send a request to.